# Какие бывают путевки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мой товарищ сказал, что покупает "***горячую путевку***". Я ему возразил, что скорее всего путевки ***горячими*** не бывают, а бывают ***горящими***. Разъясните, пожалуйста, как верно и в чем смысловая разница.

Гугль считает, что верно писать "горящие путевки". Об этом красноречиво говорит фраза: "*Возможно, вы имели в виду: "горящие путевки*" - и кол-во поисковых результатов:

- "***горячие путевки***" -  примерно 462 000 (0,28 сек.)
- "***горящие путевки***" -  примерно 3 570 000 (0,12 сек.)

**P.S.** на грамоте.ру и здесь вроде именно такой вопрос не задавали.

Comment: Гугл - не аргумет изначально.
А конкретно в данном случае он считает количество употреблений. Интреснее то, что "горячая" действительно часто употребляется.

Comment: Ну, а как планируете собирать статистику, как не гуглом и рускорпусом?

Comment: Я не планирую собирать статистику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что он, товарищ, имел в виду. Такие вещи не нормируются...

Но скорее всего путевка - горящая. От переносного смысла "гореть", т.е. подвергаться риску пропасть в скором времени. Именно так обычно и употребляют, имея в виду, например, путевку не выкупленную вовремя - и поступившую в свободную продажу.

Но с другой стороны "горячая" тоже может иметь некие права на существование. В значении, скажем, "модная", "популярная" или еще что-то такое.

Comment: Аргументация в виде определений или примеров имеется?

Comment: Гореть  
11. Разг.  
Быть под угрозой срыва, провала и т.п. из-за опоздания, упущения сроков. Путёвка горит. План горит. [] в функц. опр. Горящая путёвка.

Горячий  
Вызванный сильным чувством, выражающий сильное чувство. Г-ая вера. Г-ое желание. Г-ое стремление. Г. привет. Г. спор. Г. поцелуй. Г-ие слёзы. Г-ее участие.

(Кузнецов)

Answer (score 4):

словосочетание "горящие путевки" используется в случаях, когда говорят о тех туристических продуктах, цены на которые предельно снижены в связи с острой временной ограниченностью предложения- если их не купят, самолет просто полетит с пустыми креслами- путевка "сгорит". Словосочетание "горячее предложение"используют, когда предложение свежее и весьма привлекательное.но тоже кратковременное-видимо,по аналогии с "горячими пирожками". Потом этот товар тоже можно купить,но,как правило,цена-выше...